# Scraping website and collect all the hyperlinks using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am making a program which could take information from any website. But the program is not working.

Example-- the website is naukri.com
and we have to collect all the hyperlinks of a page:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

isc = ssl.create_default_context()
isc.check_hostname = False
isc.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

open = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-Python- 
Developer-Cloud-Analogy-Softech-Pvt-Ltd-Noida-Sector-63-Noida-1-to-2-years-250718003152src=jobsearchDesk&sid=15325422374871&xp=1&px=1&qp=python%20developer 
&srcPage=s', context = isc).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(open, 'html.parser')

tags = soup('a')

for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href', None))
```

Comment: i get a 403 forbidden....
have you tried this on any other sites?

Comment: works fine pointed to www.google.com

Comment: In what way is it not working? Do you get an error message? Does the program execute but give a wrong result?

Comment: yes I get an error 403 forbidden

Comment: That means the people in charge of that website don't want you doing what you're doing. Search for "naukri api" on google, and follow the instructions you get.

Comment: ok good. But can we get other data, for example, this is job providing a website so can we retrieve the description of the job

Answer (score 1):

I would use requests and bs4.  I was able to get this to work and I think it has the desired outcome.  Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ('https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-Python-Developer-Cloud-Analogy-Softech-Pvt-Ltd-Noida-Sector-63-Noida-1-to-2-years-250718003152src=jobsearchDesk&sid=15325422374871&xp=1&px=1&qp=python%20developer&srcPage=s')
response = requests.get(url)
page = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)

for each in links:
    print(each.get('href'))
```